# What Media-Type should I use to deliver pdf files contained in a zip archive in my RESTful API?

Tags: rest, http, http-headers, mime-types

I'am building an HTTP RESTful API and I have an operation that consist to get a resource defined in JSON format in a mongo database, and return it to the format asked by the client.

Saying the route `GET /api/media/{mediaId}` should be able to send the media in the following formats, depending the client choice:

- `json`, `xml`, `html`, `pdf`,
- and `zip`, `tar`, `tar.gz` (and for each archive type, the contained files could be a `json`, `xml`, `html` or `pdf` file, again, according to the client choice)

So I coded the server to read the `Accept` request header, to serve the matching media-type.

Ok for these formats:

- requesting a `json` file : `Accept: application/json`
- requesting a `xml` file : `Accept: application/xml`
- requesting a `html` file : `Accept: application/html`
- requesting a `pdf` file : `Accept: application/pdf`

But I have a problem to choose a correct media type for the archive formats (`zip`, `tar`, `tar.gz`)

Is the following solution acceptable ?

- a `zip` file containing `json` files : `application/zip+json`
- a `zip` file containing `xml` files : `application/zip+xml`
- a `zip` file containing `html` files : `application/zip+html`
- a `zip` file containing `pdf` files : `application/zip+pdf`
- a `tar` file containing `json` files : `application/tar+json`
- a `tar` file containing `xml` files : `application/tar+xml`
- a `tar` file containing `html` files : `application/tar+html`
- a `tar` file containing `pdf` files : `application/tar+pdf`

...

Or should I use a vendor tree ?

- requesting a `zip` file containing `json` files : `Accept: application/vnd.mycompany.zip+json`

...
- requesting a `tar` file containing `pdf` files : `Accept: application/vnd.mycompany.tar+pdf`
...

... Or should I use an other syntax ?

Comment: "application/zip+json" etc definitively is not acceptable, because a) it's not registered and b) it's not json. "+html" and "+pdf" make even less sense, as these suffixes are undefined.

Comment: Ok, I understand, even I guess. It was my first idea but I understand this is not correct. That's why I ask for better solution. Do you have an idea @JulianReschke ?